# Bios setting of sector

Tags: assembly, usb, nasm, bios

I want to boot a self-made os from usb.I seccessfully make it boot from flopy disk.But the problem happend, when I want to boot from usb, I have to read the data to disk.In flopy disk, sector and cylinder is fixed so I can easily copy it from disk.But it is not the same with usb.I want to use cheap usb to boot and my usb's structure is like this.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.5 GiB, 7996440576 bytes, 15618048 sectors(512 bytes per sector)
```

So There are no cylinder no track.When I use usb, using nasm int 0x13(AH=0x02, DL=0x08), register CL memorize sectors.I want to read 70 cylinder(flopy disk) memory  form disk, so totaly I need 10 * 2 *270 = 1400 sectors which CL only provide 2^8 = 256 sectors.How should I solve the problem?Do I have to buy new usb?

Comment: Depends how your BIOS is booting USB. If it is USB Floppy emulation then you will need a [BIOS Parameter Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block) at the beginning of your boot disk. The BIOS will fill in the basic fields including number of cylinders, heads, and sectors before it transfers control to your bootloader. Your boot code can use that drive geometry information to read from the disk. Of course CHS addressing will only allow you to access a portion of the USB disk.

Comment: I boot it using flopy-usb,but it is boring using fat12, so I want to boot without flopy and use pure usb boot(fat32 format).Thank you, I will change the way.thank you giving me advise.

Comment: BTW, because of my poor english i did not explain exactlly.I want to read the area to disk from usb the part which deserves 10 cylinder memories in flopy.

Comment: If by pure USB boot you mean USB HDD (Hard drive emulation) then you can use [Int 13/ah=42h extended disk read](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0708.htm) for anything being emulated as a hard drive. You don't specify cylinders, heads, sectors. Each sector 0 to n-1 (where n is the total number of sectors on the device). This is known as LBA (logical block addressing)

Comment: thank you.I have just tried it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702828/about-usb-boot-from-usb here is some problem i use it,could you fix it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for Michael Petch.It is easy to be solved by using lba method.